# Using value in a variable?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code:

```
insert conversion (h1, g1, s1)
 values(
'14', 
(select g1 from conversion where h1 = '14'),
'15');
```

I have to create tons of inserts manually and only want use variable for the values - less typos that way.

So want to do something like:

```
val1 = '14'
val2 = '15'
insert conversion (h1, g1, s1)
 values(
val1, 
(select g1 from conversion where h1 = val1),
val2);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: That was easy - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethink like that:

```
insert conversion (h1, g1, s1)
(select '14',g1,'15' from conversion where h1 = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the posting above - this did the trick: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html